# Pandas: Populate a specific column in dataframe by iterating through the values in existing columns to count the number of duplicated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample data containing some fake bank account information with a column called 'Account indicator' that I need to populate with based on the number of duplicated Account numbers.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
  Customer code   Account name  Account number  Account balance  Account indicator
0         20041      Tom Brown       24911467        30155.00                  
1         20041      Tom Brown       25193860           45.00                  
2         20021     Kate Perry       24092030        20450.00                  
3         20021     Kate Perry       24092007           50.00                  
4         20153    Harry Smith       20641387         5000.00                  
5         20154    Bella Smith       20641387         5000.00                  
6         20149   John William       20753196         7000.00                  
7         20144  Emily William       20753196         5000.00                  
8         20146  Rosie William       20753196         2000.00
```

1. The values in the Account indicator must start with '00' and a number. The way it works is for example (please refer to the below table), the Account number of '20641387' has **duplicated twice** as both Harry Smith and Bella Smith have the same account number. So, the Account indicator for this index is '**002**'. This is called a joint account.

The output that I am expecting to see in the Account indicator is:

```
  Customer code   Account name  Account number  Account balance  Account indicator
0         20041      Tom Brown       24911467       30155.00      001             
1         20041      Tom Brown       25193860          45.00      001             
2         20021     Kate Perry       24092030       20450.00      001             
3         20021     Kate Perry       24092007          50.00      001             
4         20153    Harry Smith       20641387        5000.00      002             
5         20154    Bella Smith       20641387        5000.00      002             
6         20149   John William       20753196        7000.00      003             
7         20144  Emily William       20753196        5000.00      003             
8         20146  Rosie William       20753196        2000.00      003
```

Furthermore, for any joint accounts shown in the indicators (e.g. 002, 003), I also need to check if the Account balances for their Account numbers are equal. From the above, we can see the number '20641387' has a balance of 5000.00 for both Harry and Bella. This is correct. However, the balances for '20753196' are incorrect as they are not equal.

I also need suggestions and helps on checking if there are any multiple accounts. This can be identified by checking if the Account name column has the same name for two different Account numbers. For example, Tom Brown and Kate Perry.

Below is what I tried and any advise would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        'Customer code': ['20041', '20041', '20021', '20021', '20153', '20154', '20149', '20144', '20146'],
        'Account name': ['Tom Brown', 'Tom Brown', 'Kate Perry', 'Kate Perry', 'Harry Smith', 'Bella Smith', 'John William', 'Emily William', 'Rosie William'],
        'Account number': ['24911467', '25193860', '24092030', '24092007', '20641387', '20641387', '20753196', '20753196', '20753196'],
        'Account balance': ['30155.00', '45.00', '20450.00', '50.00', '5000.00', '5000.00', '7000.00', '5000.00', '2000.00'],
        'Account indicator': ''}


account_details = pd.DataFrame(data)


dups_account_number = account_details.pivot_table(columns=['Account number'], aggfunc='size')

#Populate Account_Indicator with the right code
#each value in the Account indicator column = '00' + the count of its duplicated Account number
for i in account_details['Account indicator']:
    for j in account_details['Account number']:
        if account_details['Account number'].duplicated().any() == True:
            account_details['Account indicator'] = account_details['Account indicator'].apply(lambda x: '00' + dups_account_number)
            print('There are joint accounts')

        else:
            account_details['Account indicator'] = '001' #001 means 1 account number

#Here --> Code to check if the Account balances for a joint account are equal
#Could use --> if account_details['Account indicator'] != 001 to start with? Because 001 indicators are definitely not the joint account
    
    
#Here --> Code to check for multiple accounts if one name has 2 or more different Account_numbers




print(account_details)
```

Please share your thoughts! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from your description and sample code, the `Account Indicator` for joint account should depend only on the number of entries of the same `Account number`.  As such, you can group by `Account number` using [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then use [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) on [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) to get the count of entries (duplicated and single entry) of the same account number.

We further convert the count to string by [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and fill up to 3 digits by [`str.zfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), as follows:

```
account_details['Account indicator'] = (
    account_details.groupby('Account number')['Account number']
                   .transform('size')
                   .astype(str)
                   .str.zfill(3)
)
```

**Result:**

```
print(account_details)

   Customer code   Account name  Account number  Account balance Account indicator
0          20041      Tom Brown        24911467          30155.0               001
1          20041      Tom Brown        25193860             45.0               001
2          20021     Kate Perry        24092030          20450.0               001
3          20021     Kate Perry        24092007             50.0               001
4          20153    Harry Smith        20641387           5000.0               002
5          20154    Bella Smith        20641387           5000.0               002
6          20149   John William        20753196           7000.0               003
7          20144  Emily William        20753196           5000.0               003
8          20146  Rosie William        20753196           2000.0               003
```

### Part 2: To check if the Account balances for a joint account are equal

You can check whether the Account balances for a joint account are equal by grouping on `Account number` and check the unique count of `Account balance` by using [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) on [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html).  If this unique count is not equal to `1`, they are invalid joint account:

```
account_details['Joint A/C Valid?'] = (
    account_details.groupby('Account number')['Account balance']
                   .transform('nunique')
                   .eq(1)
)
```

**Result:**

```
print(account_details)

   Customer code   Account name  Account number  Account balance Account indicator  Joint A/C Valid?
0          20041      Tom Brown        24911467          30155.0               001              True
1          20041      Tom Brown        25193860             45.0               001              True
2          20021     Kate Perry        24092030          20450.0               001              True
3          20021     Kate Perry        24092007             50.0               001              True
4          20153    Harry Smith        20641387           5000.0               002              True
5          20154    Bella Smith        20641387           5000.0               002              True
6          20149   John William        20753196           7000.0               003             False
7          20144  Emily William        20753196           5000.0               003             False
8          20146  Rosie William        20753196           2000.0               003             False
```

### Part 3: To check multiple accounts for same name

You can check multiple accounts for the same name by grouping on `Account name` and check the unique count of `Account number` by using [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) on [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html).  If this unique count is greater than `1`, there are multiple accounts for the same name.

Special note: it is not uncommon to have different people of the same name opening account in the same bank.  Hence, you should take this as only the  **possible case** multiple accounts of the same **person**.  Checking by identification document which has unique number for each person is more accurate for this case.

Codes:

```
account_details['Multiple A/C?'] = (
    account_details.groupby('Account name')['Account number']
                   .transform('nunique')
                   .gt(1)
)
```

**Result:**

```
print(account_details)


   Customer code   Account name  Account number  Account balance Account indicator  Joint A/C Valid?  Multiple A/C?
0          20041      Tom Brown        24911467          30155.0               001              True           True
1          20041      Tom Brown        25193860             45.0               001              True           True
2          20021     Kate Perry        24092030          20450.0               001              True           True
3          20021     Kate Perry        24092007             50.0               001              True           True
4          20153    Harry Smith        20641387           5000.0               002              True          False
5          20154    Bella Smith        20641387           5000.0               002              True          False
6          20149   John William        20753196           7000.0               003             False          False
7          20144  Emily William        20753196           5000.0               003             False          False
8          20146  Rosie William        20753196           2000.0               003             False          False
```

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, thanks for the detailed answer! What if I would like to create a new column called 'Aggregate Balance' to add up the balance in joint accounts? Is there something like .transform('sum') to do this? So, the whole line of code would be something like the below?                                                        account_details['Aggregate Balance'] = (
    account_details.groupby('Account number')['Account balance']
                   .transform('sum')
                   .astype(float)
)

Comment: @hello  That's right!  You learned quickly :-)   One minor touch-up is that you don't need `.astype(float)` when the balances are already in float format.

Comment: I just saw your message and had tried the code without .astype(float). However, my output shows .transform('sum') doesn't add up the values but instead, it concactenates them so it looks something like this --> '7000.005000.002000.00' instead of the sum of them which should be '14000'. Do you know why?

Comment: @hello  Seems like your balance column is of string type instead of float type.  If you sure the data should be numeric, you can try to use the astype function on the column before this groupby code.  Just simply `account_details['Account balance'] = account_details['Account balance'].astype(float)`   If you don't want to change the type of this column permanently, you can put the astype before `transform`.  Putting astype at the end doesn't help.

Comment: I am playing around with the data and have modified some of the account balance to several decimal places and I would like to round up the aggregate balance column to 2 dp after the calculation by using this LOC 'decimals = pd.Series([2], index=['Aggregate Balance']) account_details.round(decimals)' but it's not working. Any tips on this? The code looks right to me.

Comment: @hello  You can try adding `.round(2)` after `transform('sum')`

Comment: I just realised that some of the result for the joint account is wrong because Tom Brown and Kate Perry are not joint accounts but the result showed TRUE. Also, John William, Emily William and Roise William are joint accounts but the result showed FALSE. The only result which showed correctly is the Smith couple.

Comment: oh that was to check on the balance of joint account. Ignore me! I confused myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to map the "Account indicator" using `groupby`/`transform`+`nunique`.

Please update your output with an example for the other part of the question on the balance:

```
account_details['Account indicator'] = (account_details.groupby('Account number')
                                                       ['Account name']
                                                       .transform('nunique')
                                                       .map('{:03d}'.format)
                                       )
```

output:

```
  Customer code   Account name Account number Account balance Account indicator
0         20041      Tom Brown       24911467        30155.00               001
1         20041      Tom Brown       25193860           45.00               001
2         20021     Kate Perry       24092030        20450.00               001
3         20021     Kate Perry       24092007           50.00               001
4         20153    Harry Smith       20641387         5000.00               002
5         20154    Bella Smith       20641387         5000.00               002
6         20149   John William       20753196         7000.00               003
7         20144  Emily William       20753196         5000.00               003
8         20146  Rosie William       20753196         2000.00               003
```

Balance:

```
account_details['Balance indicator'] = (account_details.groupby('Account number')
                                                       ['Account balance']
                                                       .transform('nunique')
                                                       .eq(1)
                                                       .map({True: 'valid balance', False: 'invalid balance'})
                                       )
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thanks for the solution!  For the other parts of my question, 1) Check if the Account balances for their Account numbers are equal. I just need to print a message to say 'valid balance' or else, print 'invalid balance identified' with the associated Account name and Account number

Comment: @hello the you can use the same principle, if nunique is 1, the balance is valid. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
df['Account number'] = df['Account number'].astype(str)
counts_ser = df['Account number'].value_counts()

# Now we create a dictionary for using as a mapper in replace method
mapper = {k: str(counts_ser[k]).zfill(3) for k in df['Account number'].value_counts().index}
df['Account indicator'] = df['Account number'].replace(mapper)
```

Output:

```
    Account number  Account indicator
0   24911467             001
1   25193860             001
2   24092030             001
3   24092007             001
4   20641387             002
5   20641387             002
6   20753196             003
7   20753196             003
8   20753196             003
```